# Azure Function .NET5 (isolated) throws when using [EventGridTrigger] EventGridEvent as parameter

Tags: c#, azure-functions

After upgrade to .NET5 for Azure Function this signature throws the exception below.

I've implemented it according to the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid-trigger?tabs=csharp%2Cbash

```
 [Function(nameof(CustomerCreated))]
 public async Task CustomerCreated([EventGridTrigger] EventGridEvent eventGridEvent, FunctionContext functionContext)
 {

   // My implementation

 }
```

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Deserialization of types without a
> parameterless constructor, a singular parameterized constructor, or a
> parameterized constructor annotated with 'JsonConstructorAttribute' is
> not supported. Type 'Azure.Messaging.EventGrid.EventGridEvent'. Path:
> $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.'

How can I receive the event from EventGrid?

Answer (score 13):

The new way of doing this seems to be `CloudEvent` from the `Azure.Messaging` namespace.

(A side note is that the data properties are case-sensitive, I'm not sure if they were before.)

```
public async Task CustomerCreated([EventGridTrigger] CloudEvent eventGridEvent, FunctionContext functionContext)
{
     // [...]
}
```

UPDATE:

This breaks when deploying to Azure and receiving events from a real event grid with an Azure Function as endpoints. But works fine when testing locally using ngrok and webhook. Back to square one.

After endless googling with outdated examples I found a note in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#bindings), pointing to [this example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/blob/main/samples/Extensions/EventGrid/EventGridFunction.cs) showing that you need to create a custom type (looking just like the EventGridEvent).

After testing I found that this actually works:

Pass a `string` instead of `EventGridEvent` and parse the actual event with the utility function from `EventGridEvent`.

```
[Function(nameof(CustomerCreated))]
public async Task CustomerCreated([EventGridTrigger] string data, FunctionContext functionContext)
{
    var eventGridEvent = EventGridEvent.Parse(BinaryData.FromString(data));
    
    // Rest of code
}
```

Another related caveat is that you can't create the function from the portal but need to run it from the command line like:

```
az eventgrid event-subscription create --name customer-created \
    --source-resource-id <event-grid-topic-resource-id> \
    --endpoint <azure-func-resource-id> --endpoint-type azurefunction
```

(The resource id:s can be found at http://resources.azure.com/)

Hello Microsoft;

Running Azure Functions on .NET5 doesn't feel very GA with this approach. I really hope to be able to pass typed objects like EventGridEvent from other Azure services with official libraries.

I really think that the EventGridEvent on .NET5/dotnet-isolated should be compatible with Azure Functions at the same level as on previous .NET versions and as in the public examples.

Comment: If you create a new project with the Visual Studio Template for Azure Functions and choose ".NET 5 isolated" as the type, and Event Grid as the trigger, it will generate a class called MyEvent that works. The object Data property will end up being of type System.Text.Json.JsonElement, which is nice. I agree the documentation is not current for this.

Comment: Seconding the argument that there should be a library `EventGridEvent` class and we don't have to create that library of classes ourselves. The fact the template generates a custom class mimicking the shape of `EventGridEvent` further highlights the issue.

Comment: For users who would also like to publish custom events using `Azure.Messaging.EventGrid.EventGridPublisherClient`, do the following: 
`await eventGridPublisherClient.SendEventAsyc(new BinaryData(customEvent))`. This is applicable for all isolated-process Azure Functions running in `dotnet-isolated` mode. More info can be found here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/event-grid-ga/

Comment: I am facing the same issue with the in-process app. I was trying to add the a EventTriggrer Function in a function that is already running. With the above mentioned solution, I am able to trigger the method but Binary data conversion fails. Any help?