# Receive EventGridEvent from Azure.Messaging.EventGrid in Azure function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

After switching from Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid package to Azure.Messaging.EventGrid the following signature gets broken:

```
[FunctionName("MyFuncEG")]
public Task RunEventGrid([EventGridTrigger] EventGridEvent data)
```

With this exception message:

> Unable to find a constructor to use for type
> Azure.Messaging.EventGrid.EventGridEvent. A class should either have a
> default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor
> marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path '[0].topic'

I read this post and would like to know if there is any update for this? Should I use CloudEvent (this has its caveats?) or I need to write my custom type for EventGridEvent like described in that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67918950/azure-function-net5-isolated-throws-when-using-eventgridtrigger-eventgridev) or something else? Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid* package should be also updated. In my case I updated it to Version="3.0.0-beta.3" and it gets working.